# Detect active touchscreen on Linux (and if multitouch)

Tags: c++, linux, touch, linux-device-driver, multi-touch

I need the Linux equivalent for the following Windows code:

```
auto touchCap(GetSystemMetrics(SM_DIGITIZER));
if (!(touchCap & NID_READY)) LOG("WARNING: No active digitizer detected")
if (!(touchCap & NID_MULTI_INPUT)) LOG("WARNING: No multi-touch digitizer detected")
```

Note that it's not checking if a touchscreen driver is simply present, but if there is a currently *active* touch device. I also need to know if it's multitouch or not.

Comment: Does the driver for this device exist in linux? Do they have an api that you can look at?

Comment: The code above is device-agnostic, which is exactly what I need for the Linux port as well. Given that the Linux kernel presents touch messages in a device-agnostic manner[1], surely there's a way to do the above as well without checking some huge list of possible drivers and querying their varying APIs.  [1] https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt

Answer (score 1):

There might not be an exact equivalent, as I have seen differences in the way Windows and Linux event libraries are designed, but have you taken a look at the SDL Library? This is the event library that I have seen used for some recent Linux projects.

https://wiki.libsdl.org/

I've also heard that SFML is pretty nice.

http://www.sfml-dev.org/